# Why does this C code compile and link without error?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

It compiles, links and runs without error.

test.c

```
#include "foo.h"                                                                 

int main()                                                                       
{                                                                                
    foo(4);                                                                      
    foo();                                                                       
    foo("cheese");                                                               
    foo("cheese", 8);                                                            
}
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H                                                                    
#define FOO_H                                                                    
int foo();                                                                       
#endif
```

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                               
#include "foo.h"                                                                 

int foo(int a)                                                                   
{                                                                                
    printf("Hello\n");                                                           
}
```

Compiled with gcc test.c foo.c

Comment: I made a similar mistake in a project, was surprised that the compiler is ok with this. Makes it hard to find errors.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wmissing-prototypes`

Comment: The reason is because if your function is defined as `int foo();`, it can accept any number of arguments without error. If you define the function in the header as `int foo(void);`, your example above will generate numerous errors.